# Is there a way to do an Intersect in SQL, that not only returns a geom column, but also all the attribute information?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to do an intersect in SQL using the programme pgAdmin 4. I have managed to do an intersect which only returns the resulting geom column.

I would like to have all the Attribute Information from all the other columns, too though. Just like when you do an intersect in QGIS or ArcGIS.

Here is what I have used that got me only the geom column (I am using colours to make it less complicated and easier to read):

```
CREATE TABLE public.green AS
SELECT ST_INTERSECTION (b.geom, y.geom_2)
FROM public.blue b, public.yellow y
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(b.geom, y.geom_2) = 't';
```

I know the public isn't necessary here, but I have more than one Schema that I use. So I thought it would be better to add the Schema here so all parts are accounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to change the select statement, for example this will grab everything out of both tables.

```
CREATE TABLE public.green AS
SELECT b.*, y.*,ST_INTERSECTION (b.geom, y.geom_2)
FROM public.blue b, public.yellow y
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(b.geom, y.geom_2);
```

Comment: I tried it using Create View (create table processed too long and I am not too sure why, could be due to size of the dataset, or something else). With your Statement I got all the Attribute Information from both tables but I didn't get an intersected geom column. What I am looking to achieve is an Output just like what you get when you do an intersect in QGIS/ArcGIS, but in SQL. Is it possible to get both the 'new' geom column and the Attribute Information that belongs to it?

Comment: you can put anything you like in the select statement - probably best to go for just the intersection and attributes you need

Comment: Ahh I see, I tried to incorporate the st_intersection part, too but didn't do it correctly. That's why it didn't work. Thanks for updating your answer and your help! Much appreciated :)